# How to set the signature type of a function statement in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a function signature type like this:

```js
type MyFunc = (foo: string) => string
```

How can I use this signature to set the type of a function statement (**not** function expression)? For example when I have an array of functions like

```js
[(foo) => foo + "bar", () => "bar"]
```

**Without setting a type for the array**, can I somehow enforce the signature of the functions inside the array so that `() => "bar"` throws an error because of a type mismatch? I imagine something like this:

```
[((foo) => foo + "bar"): MyFunc, (() => "bar"): MyFunc]
```

Obviously this is not valid syntax. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: YOu can do it if you use extra function. See playground: tsplay.dev/mqvjjW ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as`, but `() => string` is currently a valid subtype of `(foo: string) => string`, so you will not get an error. (The implementation is free to ignore any arguments.)

```
type MyFunc = (foo: string) => string

[
    ((foo) => foo + "bar") as MyFunc, // No error
    (() => "bar") as MyFunc,          // No error
    ((x: number) => "bar") as MyFunc, // Error
]
```